# Is it possible to deliberately make edit-reviewers look bad by abusing the edit-suggestion grace period?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I just noticed that I had a little mistake (missed a space between 2 words) in an [edit I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20889565). At this point this edit suggestion already had 1 review and after my edit the review was still there.

Is there a threshold of changes to an edit suggestion that a review gets revoked?

Otherwise I could vandalize my edit and this would put reviewer 1 in a bad light.

As review histories are sometimes considered for bans or just blaming people on meta for bad actions, this would decrease the credibility of reviewer 1.

Is this possible or are there things preventing such abuse?

A timeline of edits to the suggestions comes to my mind (and maybe then that it is also possible to mark the revision that was reviewed), but this is probably a lot of work for a very small problem.

Comment: The attack surface seems rather small... and the best possible cure (invalidating the review when an edit is done during the grace period) seems rather harsh for such small window.

Comment: The hypothetical _attacker_ has no control on who is going to review their suggested edit, or when; so keep making edits with the hope that they get approved during the grace period just vandalize the content and cast a bad light on a random reviewer? I don't know if there is much that really needs to be fixed.

Comment: @yivi What is the grace period for suggested edits? I am not sure the new title is accurate... And I do not say it NEEDS fixing still I want to report possible problematic behavior.

Comment: @Dukeling I know that. But what is the grace period for edits to suggested edits? I do not think that this exists at least it has to be more than 5 minutes, because I would say my edit was much later. This is also why I question the validity of the title change.

Comment: @KamiKaze Apparently [the grace period is while your edit is in review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202282/what-happens-when-i-edit-my-suggested-edit/202288#202288).

Comment: There aren't any consequences to taking the wrong action on a non-audit review (that I know of). That's what audits are for.

Comment: @Dukeling except for the occasional witch hunt on meta^^

Comment: If there's a meta witch hunt, I'd expect an employee could probably look up edits made in the grace period, and it would be worse for the editor than for the reviewer. Also, you can't really target a reviewer. I see no real reason to abuse this, even if it might be possible.

Comment: @yivi If you have a 10k account at hand, you can probably snipe regular reviewers by watching the latest reviews tab. Granted, that does sound like a giant waste of time.

Comment: Changed the tag to discussion since it is more a hypothetical question about perception rather than a question about the site software not working correctly.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth: You don't need to have a specific name in mind to want to ruin someone's day.

Comment: @BoltClock Fair enough, I guess anything that can be exploited on a sock with 1 rep should be treated seriously

Answer (score 14):

Theoretically, yes, you could vandalize your own edit suggestion to make a reviewer look bad. However, this is unlikely for a number of reasons. First, reviewer history is not typically viewed for actual reasons (rather than just out of curiosity) by anyone except moderators and then only in rare cases, if ever, as far as I know. You have to go into the queue history and go page by page to see a list of previous review items... it's quite tedious (I suppose you *may* be able to do it with SEDE a bit easier, though). It's also unlikely that a user or users would vandalize enough of their own suggested edits that a single reviewer would be caught with more than one or two "bad-looking" review approvals without the editor getting flagged.

It's much more likely that your edit would be rejected anyway after such vandalism, and you would get penalized or messaged by a moderator.

Further, the bar for acting on bad reviews is quite high - in most cases moderators or users will just message a user or comment on their most recent post asking them to take a closer look when reviewing. If necessary, the moderator could apply a review ban or work with a CM to look deeper into the situation.

Comment: If the person wanting to look at review history desires to see the review history of a single user, then they can go to the user's profile➞"activity" tab➞"all actions" sub-tab➞"reviews" sub-sub-tab, which lists all the reviews that user has done. I agree that it's inconvenient to look at the overall review history of everyone who completed a type of review, but it's easy to do for a single user.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that review activity showed up publicly in the All Actions tab.